# Stochastic variables independent given Tau

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stopping-times, independence

Say we have a filtration $(\mathbb{F}_s)$, and a stopping time $\tau$ w.r.t. to that filtration.Let $X_t$ be a continuous stochastic process (not required to be adapted to the mentioned filtration), such that $X_t$ is independent of $(\mathbb{F}_s)_{s\leq s_0}$ for $s_0\leq t$

I strongly believe that it holds that for all $c>0$ (correct me if its not intuitively clear)
$$P(X_{\tau}>c\vert \tau=s)=P(X_{s}>c).$$
 or atleast
$$P(X_{\tau+\epsilon}> c\vert \tau=s)=P(X_{s+\epsilon}> c).$$
Can anybody help me prove it?

**What i have tried:**
Well in discrete time the proof of the 2nd statement is straight forward
$$P(X_{\tau+1}>c\vert \tau=j)=\dfrac{P(X_{\tau+1}>c, \tau=j)}{P(\tau=j)}=\dfrac{P(X_{j+1}>c, \tau=j)}{P(\tau=j)}=P(X_{j+1}>c).$$ 
I have troubles making it work in continuous time. Our definition of 
$P(X_{\tau}>c\vert \tau=s)$ is the function $\phi(s)$ such that $\phi(\tau)$ is a.s the random variable $E(1_{(X_{\tau}>c)}\vert \tau).$

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia page on conditional expectation, the first basic property is that if $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{H}$ then $E(X|\mathcal{H})=E(X)$ and a proof is given on Wikipedia.  So what you need to show is that the random variable $1_{X_t>c}$ is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\tau=t\}$ (which is a sub-algebra of $\mathcal{F}_t$).

Comment: It is not generally true that $E(X\vert Y=y)=E(X\vert \sigma(Y=y))$, so i don't think your argument is right, or do i miss-understand your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\tau_n = \frac{[2^n\tau] + 1}{2^n}$$ Note that $\tau_n$ is discrete and $\tau_n \downarrow \tau$.

Now use the result you have for the discrete cases $$P(X_{\tau_n}>c\vert \tau_n=j)=\dfrac{P(X_{\tau_n}>c, \tau_n=j)}{P(\tau_n=j)}=\dfrac{P(X_{j}>c, \tau_n=j)}{P(\tau_n=j)}=P(X_{j}>c). \quad j \in \Bbb{Z}_+/ 2^n$$

Now to the continous case note that since $X_t$ is continuous $X_{\tau_n} \to X_\tau$ and
$$ 1_{[X_{\tau} > c]}  = \lim_n 1_{[X_{\tau_n} > c]} $$

Therefore $$ E[1_{[X_{\tau_n} > c]} \mid \tau] = \sum_{j \in \Bbb{Z}_+/2^n} P(X_{j}>c)1_{[2^n \tau] + 1  = j}  = g^n(\tau)$$

Assume X is bounded, therefore by the bounded convergence theorem

$$ E[1_{[X_{\tau} > c]} \mid \tau] = \lim_n E[1_{[X_{\tau_n} > c]} \mid \tau] = \lim_n \sum_{j \in \Bbb{Z}_+/2^n} P(X_{j}>c)1_{[2^n \tau] + 1  = j} = \lim_n g^n(\tau) = g(\tau) $$

as for each $t$ $g(t) = \lim_n g^n(t) = P(X_t > c)$ is the limit of $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable functions, the limit is also  $\mathcal{F}_\tau$, and the claim follows.

To the general case (when $X$ is unbounded) note by $X^M = (X \wedge M) \vee 0$. $$X^M =\begin{cases}M & \text{ if } X>M \\X & \text{ if } 0<X\leq M \\0 & \text{ if } X\leq 0 \\\end{cases}$$

Now use the monotone congergence theorem.
$$ E[1_{[X_{\tau} > c]} \mid \tau] = \lim_M E[1_{[X^M_{\tau} > c]} \mid \tau] = \lim_M P(X^M_{\tau} > c) = P(X_\tau> c) $$

Comment: Cool thanks !  A few comments:
We need $1_{X_{\tau_n}>c}$ to converge to $1_{X_{\tau}>c}$ almost surely. I dont think it is true per default because things can happen on the event $(X_\tau=c)$.  However, in my case this is a null-set ! :) 

Another thing, as far s i can see, you apply bounded convergence theorem on $1_{X_{\tau_n}}>c$ which is bounded no matter if $X$ is or not, so you don't need to split in cases there i guess.

Comment: You are right about both comments, thank you for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your notation, and don't generally understand a lot of notation from stochastic analysts but would like to improve so I'll give it a shot.

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{F})$ be the probability space and filtration, and $g_t(\omega)=1_{X_t(\omega)>c}$.  The question, interpreted into this abstract notation, is to show that $E(g_\tau|\tau)(\omega)=E(g_s)$ whenever $\tau(\omega)=s$, assuming that $X_t$ is independent of $\mathbb{F}_t$ for all $t$.

According to Wikipedia's page on conditional expectation, $E(g_\tau|\tau)=E(g_\tau|\mathcal{H})$ where the $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathcal{H}=\{\tau^{-1}(B):B\subset \mathbb{R}^+\ {\rm is\ Borel}\}$.  Let $\mathcal{H}_t\subset \mathbb{F}_t$ be the restriction for $B\subset [0,t]$.  Independence implies that $E(g_s|\mathcal{H_s})=E(g_s)$.  When restricted to $\{\omega:\tau(\omega)=s\}=O\in \mathcal{H}_s$ we have that $E(g_s|\mathcal{H}_s)=E(g_\tau|\mathcal{H}_s)$.  Still restricting to $O$, $E(g_\tau|\mathcal{H}_s)=E(g_\tau|\mathcal{H})$, because $\{A\cap O: A\in \mathcal{H}_s\}=\{A\cap O: A\in \mathcal{H}\}$.

I think the notation is a pain and maybe I miss the point of the question.  It does not seem to need any continuity, although continuity might help if you only had independence of $X_t$ and $\mathbb{F}_s$ for $s<t$.

Comment: Can you explain the part "When restricted to $\{ \omega : \tau(\omega)=s\}=O\in H_s$ we have that $E(gs\vert H_s)=E(g_\tau\vert H_s).$ " ?

Comment: There are no non-trivial subsets of $O$ in $\mathcal{H}_s$ so measurability implies that $E(g_s|\mathcal{H}_s)$ and $E(g_\tau|\mathcal{H}_s)$ are constant on $O$ and by definition they integrate to the same thing.  There might be a problem if $O$ has measure zero so maybe you would only get that they agree for almost every $s$ (using elements of $\mathcal{H}_s$ like $\tau^{-1}([s_0,s])$ and a similar argument using measurability and that the integral on all measurable subsets agree.)  In this case continuity would be needed to make a statement for all $s$.

Comment: Sorry,i still dont understand the argument of why the two variables $E(g_s\vert H_s) , E(G_{\tau}\vert H_s)$ are equal on O.

Also, it is not unlikely that $\tau$ has a continuous distribution over $\mathbb{R}_+$ meaning that $O$ has measure zero for all $s\geq 0$.